# How to use UIPageViewController with storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I have been trying to implement a UIPageViewController in my game. I have looked around the web and apple documentation but none of them seems to help with respect to storyboard. I have come across [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application) but it uses multiple xib files without storyboard.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as in how I can implement this?.

PS : I simply want to implement a book like structure each page containing a view controller with data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old question but I found this (translated from italian) [tutorial](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=it&u=http://www.devapp.it/wordpress/t111-come-utilizzare-uipageviewcontroller-con-lo-storyboard.html&prev=/search?q=uipageviewcontroller%2bexample&start=20&safe=active&sa=N&hl=en&biw=1597&bih=674&sa=X&ei=7LF3Uej8KcGAtAa8zoGYBg&ved=0CE0Q7gEwBTgU), in hopes of helping anyone.